# How to dynamically fetch multiple audio data into asset_audio_player list from firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, audio-player, just-audio

I have been trying to use the `assets_audio_player` for a playlist. I want to dynamically fetch data from firestore collection, but I can't get all the songs into the playlist.

I have been trying to dynamically populate the audios list with data from firestore without success.

I have 3 songs in the db collection, but I was only able to get 1 of them into the audios list.

I don't want to add the song urls statically as shown in the plugin example. Can anyone please help?

Here are my attempts:

First I fetched the data using a StreamBuilder and pass it to the `AudioPlayerBackgroundPlaylist();`

```js
children:

snapShot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
  return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (
          context) => AudioPlayerBackgroundPlaylist (
            song: document.data()['song'],
            songTitle: document.data()['songTitle'],
            artistName: document.data()['artist']['artistName'],
          )));
```

Here's the `AudioPlayerBackgroundPlaylist` page where I expected to see the songs, but I only see one of the three songs in the db collection

```js
class AudioPlayerBackgroundPlaylist extends StatefulWidget {
  String songTitle, artistName, song;

  AudioPlayerBackgroundPlaylist(
      {this.songTitle,
      this.artistName,
      this.song,      
      });
  @override
  _AudioPlayerBackgroundPlaylistState createState() =>
      _AudioPlayerBackgroundPlaylistState();
}

class _AudioPlayerBackgroundPlaylistState
    extends State<AudioPlayerBackgroundPlaylist> {
  final AssetsAudioPlayer audioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();

  List<Audio> audios;

  @override
  void initState() {
    audios = [
          Audio.network(
              widget.song,
              metas: Metas(title: widget.songTitle, artist: widget.artistName)),
        ]
    super.initState();
    setupPlaylist();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    audioPlayer.dispose();
  }

  void setupPlaylist() async {
    audioPlayer.open(
        Playlist(audios: audios),
        showNotification: true,
        autoStart: false);
  }

  playMusic() async {
    await audioPlayer.play();
  }

  pauseMusic() async {
    await audioPlayer.pause();
  }

  skipPrevious() async {
    await audioPlayer.previous();
  }

  skipNext() async {
    await audioPlayer.next();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: audioPlayer.builderIsPlaying(builder: (context, isPlaying) {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                  iconSize: 50,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.skip_previous_rounded),
                  onPressed: () => skipPrevious()),
              IconButton(
                  iconSize: 50,
                  icon: Icon(isPlaying
                      ? Icons.pause_rounded
                      : Icons.play_arrow_rounded),
                  onPressed: () => isPlaying ? pauseMusic() : playMusic()),
              IconButton(
                  iconSize: 50,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.skip_next_rounded),
                  onPressed: () => skipNext())
            ],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code.

Comment: @TarikHuber Hi, i have edited the question and added part of my code. I look forward to your kind help. Thank you

Comment: You are sending to `AudioPlayerBackgroundPlaylist` just a single song. You would need to revrite `AudioPlayerBackgroundPlaylist` to accept an `audio` List to use it. But I can say that it's not easy to work with that. I also use the same lib in one of my Apps. Very strange and bugy lib.

Comment: Thank you for your response, now i understand what's going on. Problem is that i don't know how to make AudioPlayerBackgroundPlaylist receive an audio List instead of a String and even how to send the List from the StreamBuilder page. Could you point me to any guide or something on this? Thank you again for your help